# How to get sizes of VMWare VM disks using PyVMomi

Tags: pyvmomi

Can anyone guide me how to calculate the sizes of disks attached to VMWare VMs using PyVMomi?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know how to get a vm object, you can do:

```
for device in vm.config.hardware.device:
    if type(device).__name__ == 'vim.vm.device.VirtualDisk':
        print 'SIZE', device.deviceInfo.summary
```

On a 1TB disk this prints:

```
SIZE 1,073,741,824 KB
```

There are probably better ways.  I'm just getting going with pyvmomi.

Answer (score 0):

For more in depth information, refer reply to the question: [Getting an instance's actual used (allocated) disk space in vmware with pyvmomi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666195/getting-an-instances-actual-used-allocated-disk-space-in-vmware-with-pyvmomi/38868247#38868247)

Using the following approach and code, you can get DiskPath, DiskCapacity and FreeSpace of the disk, you want to query for. Hope it helps.