# Getting an instance's actual used (allocated) disk space in vmware with pyvmomi

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I've recently started using pyvmomi to get a detailed inventory of vmware servers prior to migrating instances into AWS.

In the vcenter web interface, or vsphere client, I can inspect an instance and see its disks, and it'll tell me the disk size (provisioned), and how much of it is in use (used storage).

From the samples github repo (https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples) I could quickly learn how to get information on the instances, so getting the disk size is trivial (there's even a question in SO that shows an easy way to get the drives - [How to get sizes of VMWare VM disks using PyVMomi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026470/how-to-get-sizes-of-vmware-vm-disks-using-pyvmomi)), but I can't figure out how to get the actual used storage the web/client can show.

So, how do I get the used space for a given instance disks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the ***freespace*** from the VM via **PyVMomi** first you have to check if the *VMware tools* for VM's is installed on your system or not. For checking if its installed, check from your *VM's guest information from its summary page (via MOB)* if it shows:

1. **toolsStatus - VirtualMachineToolsStatus - "toolsNotInstalled"**:
   This means that you have to install the VMware tools to your respective VM, you can refer following links to install: a)https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=491&downloadGroup=VMTOOLS1000 or, b)https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018377
2. **toolsStatus - VirtualMachineToolsStatus - "toolsOk"**: This means that your VM already has VMware tools installed, and you can get the *diskPath*, *capacity* and *freeSpace* properties values from **vim.vm.GuestInfo.DiskInfo**. (If you install VMware tools manually as mentioned above, following should be true)

Once, the above environment is set, you can get the respective information from your VM via following code:

```
service_instance = None
vcenter_host = "HOSTNAME"
vcenter_port = NUMERIC_PORT
vcenter_username = "USERNAME"
vcenter_password = "PASSWORD"
vmName = "VM_NAME";
try:
    #For trying to connect to VM
    service_instance = connect.SmartConnect(host=vcenter_host, user=vcenter_username, pwd=vcenter_password, port=vcenter_port, sslContext=context)

    atexit.register(connect.Disconnect, service_instance)

    content = service_instance.RetrieveContent()

    container = content.rootFolder  # starting point to look into
    viewType = [vim.VirtualMachine]  # object types to look for
    recursive = True  # whether we should look into it recursively
    containerView = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(
    container, viewType, recursive)
    #getting all the VM's from the connection    
    children = containerView.view
    #going 1 by 1 to every VM
    for child in children:
        vm = child.summary.config.name
        #check for the VM
        if(vm == vmName):
            vmSummary = child.summary
            #get the diskInfo of the selected VM
            info = vmSummary.vm.guest.disk
            #check for the freeSpace property of each disk
            for each in info:
                #To get the freeSPace in GB's
                diskFreeSpace = each.freeSpace/1024/1024/1024
```

Hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks Sumit, this will be really helpful.

I was in search of a solution that didn't involve using vmware tools, as the vmware client can show provisioned/used space even without it, but I didnt specify this in the question, and frankly this is good enough for my immediate needs.

Comment: If you're looking to get the percentage of the disk space used for the `/home` disk (which is what I was looking for) you can check `if each.diskPath == '/home'` and then use the properties `freeSpace` and `capacity`: `(1 - float(each.freeSpace) / each.capacity) * 100`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using above vSphere API 4.0,
please have a look this [vmware documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.vm.Summary.StorageSummary.html)

here is my vm configuration
[image]

**json dump**

```
vm = <find your vm> 
jsonify(vm.summary.storage)

# dump output
(vim.vm.Summary.StorageSummary) { 
    dynamicType = <unset>, 
    dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [], 
    committed = 8591326612, # 8GB (first commmited hdd)
    uncommitted = 54964532611, # 20GB + 30GB (two added hdd)
    unshared = 8589934592, 
    timestamp = 2018-07-03T07:23:26.715559Z }
```

**python code**

```
...
vm = <find your vm> 
#disk size in byte
disk_size = vm.summary.storage.committed + vm.summary.storage.uncommitted
```